# Avoid generating random integer in different functions

Tags: java, arrays

My function:

```
public int[] generateRandomInteger(){
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 10;
        arr[i] = randomInt;
    }        
    return arr;
}
```

The problem is: when I use **arr** in another function, it will generate a different array of 100 integer numbers. How can I avoid this problem ? I only want to use exactly the array that generate from the function above.

Any help would be appriciated !

Comment: Make that array an instance field? Or class field?

Comment: Could you please give me an example ? Thanks so much !

Comment: That means that the code you wrote is working as it should be. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `arr` variable to be common to all objects.Then use *static variable*.

```
static int[] arr = new int[100];
public void setRandomIntegerArray(){
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 10;
      arr[i] = randomInt;
  }
}
public int[] getRandomIntegerArray(){
    return arr;
}
```

If you want to have `arr` variable to be separate for each object.Then use *instance variable*.

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
public void setRandomIntegerArray(){
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 10;
      arr[i] = randomInt;
  }
}
public int[] getRandomIntegerArray(){
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just generate once, and use it always.

```
int[] array = generateRandomInteger();
// operate on it...
// or pass it to another function
modifyArray(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Where

```
public void modifyArray(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] += 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a seed when you create your random instance. Every random instance created with the same seed will return the same results if calls are made in the same order to both of them. But I agree with Rohit Jain that you probably want to keep the one instance of the array around instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int[] generatedArray = null; //This keeps the array you generated
private int randomIdx = 0; //This keeps track of where you are

//This function controls access to your random numbers.
public int getNextInt() {
  if (this.generatedArray == null) {
    this.generatedArray = generateRandomInteger();
    randomIdx = 0;
  }

  return generatedArray[randomIdx++];
}

//Technically this doesn't need to be in the same class
//We keep it untouched, though, in case you need the functionality as-is
public int[] generateRandomInteger(){
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 10;
        arr[i] = randomInt;
    }        
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a singleton instance in this way

```
public class ArrayIntGenerator {
  private int[] array;
  private ArrayIntGenerator()
  {
      this.array = new int[100];
      Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 10;
            this.array[i] = randomInt;
        }
  }
  private static ArrayIntGenerator instance = null;

  public final static ArrayIntGenerator getInstance() {
    if(null == instance) instance = new ArrayIntGenerator();
    return instance;
  }

  public int[] getArray() {
    return this.array;
  }
}
```

and access to `int[]` with `ArrayIntGenerator.getInstance().getArray()`

Comment: `null == instance` this is not C++